# angularjs route to resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a big number of angularjs routes in my app. I would like to set access to these route based on some user permission levels.

```
angular.module('myApp').run(['$rootScope', 'someAuthFactory', function($rootScope, someAuthFactory) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
            $rootScope.permissions = someAuthFactory.getPermssionLevels();
            $rootScope.specialRights = $rootScope.permissions.indexOf('superRole') > -1;
...
```

and here is one of my routes:

```
.state("dashboard.overview", {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "app/dashboard.html",
    resolve: {
        roles: ['rootScope', function (rootScope) {
            return $rootScope.specialRights;}]
        },
```

so this code works, but if i want to add this:

```
resolve: {
        roles: ['rootScope', function (rootScope) {
            return $rootScope.specialRights;}]
        }
```

to every route, it is gonna be duplicate code, or if I want to lookup some other role, it is gonna be boring.
Could we make the **resolve** part much smaller and much cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

create a variable in config function on top of the routes like this

```
var resolveRoles = ['rootScope', function (rootScope) {
   return $rootScope.specialRights;}]
}
```

and use it in every route like this,

```
   .state("dashboard.overview", {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "app/dashboard.html",
        resolve: {
            roles: resolveRoles
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service/factory, which shares $rootScope.specialRights. Just init $rootScope.specialRights in the service in the first resolve of your route e.g.

```
 .state("dashboard", {
    url: ...
    templateUrl: ...
    resolve: {
        roles: ['rootScope', function (rootScope) {
                YourServiceOrFactory.setSpecialRights($rootScope.specialRights);
                return $rootScope.specialRights
     }]
},
```

And there where you need it

```
  YourServiceOrFactory.getSpecialRights()
```

It does not have to be in other resolves, just in your controller of your route or in your directive/component. Much cleaner and performanter than multiple resovles.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already setting this property in `$rootScope`, it is an overkill to use `resolve` in all of your routes, just to get a variable value, and of course, `resolve` is not designed for such purposes.

Instead, just inject the `$rootScope` in your controller and use `$rootScope.specialRights` in the controller.

**Example:**

In your controller, service, directive, or component, you can inject the `$rootScope` like this:

```
angular.module('your_module')
  .controller('your_controller', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    // Access $rootScope.permissions or $rootScope.specialRights here
  }];
```

Comment: can you give an example?